# Hard time parsing links in webpage using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-webbrowser

I am having a hard time parsing all of the links in this webpage: https://recordings.engineering.illinois.edu:8443/ess/portal/section/8a3458dc-ed31-4c93-8e3e-3b64b1f89fe8
I basically want to parse all of the links, then only keep the Video File links you see to download each lecture.

import httplib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

```
http = httplib2.Http()
status, response =      http.request('https://recordings.engineering.illinois.edu:8443/ess/portal/section/8a3458dc-ed31-4c93-8e3e-3b64b1f89fe8')

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser",parse_only      =SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print link['href']
```

The above is my code that should parse the links.

Then I'll use something along the lines of `webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)` to open a new tab on each link (that's all that is required to begin downloading each video).

It seems that beautifulsoup is having a hard time getting the links for this particular URL. It works with other more simple pages quite well. Any ideas on what the issue is?

Comment: Your actual webpage is in an `<iframe>`, but all of the links are dynamically loaded with JavaScript. Load the page and inspect the requests with your browser's developer tools and you should see a JSON response like this with some info: https://recordings.engineering.illinois.edu:8443/ess/client/api/sections/8a3458dc-ed31-4c93-8e3e-3b64b1f89fe8/section-data.json?pageSize=20

Comment: An option to achieve what you want is getting the link of each thumbnail of lecture (e.g. https://engr-media.engr.illinois.edu/ess/1616/5/c4ca6995-aff3-41e9-950a-ffd4a2fb7683/synopsis/low/02340050.jpg) and use a regex to extract this piece from URL (c4ca6995-aff3-41e9-950a-ffd4a2fb7683), which is the lecture code or something like. After this, just put the picked up code and  replace it on the download link (https://recordings.engineering.illinois.edu:8443/ess/echo/presentation/<code_goes_here>/media.m4v?downloadOnly=true).